# Is there a way to bind to an array of components in angular and render those in the current component using ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-components

To preface, this is related to the following question:

[Is there a way to programmatically render a component in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62380246/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-render-a-component-in-angular)

Is it possible to render dynamic components from an array in the view model? (similar to using the ng-template for a single component from the aforementioned question).

```
<div *ngFor="let component of components">
    <Do something here to render component>
</div>
```

I worked with KnockoutJs prior and it was fairly easy to accomplish this with something like the following in the view:

```
<!-- ko foreach: someArrayOfComponents -->
    <!-- ko component: { componentName: 'some-component', params: someComponentViewModel } --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: This might help you: https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#ngfor. And this: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2

Comment: The documentation doesn't really mention iterating through dynamic components. It seems to only talk about when the components are specifically typed. However, is this possible:

<ng-template *ngFor="let component of components #referenceid>

Comment: What would the components array look like? Components in angular need to be created using a componentFactory. What you want is very possible, but it requires some more functionality.

Comment: I don't know exactly how that components property should look on the view model. I saw you can inject ViewChildren like this: `@ViewChildren(Item) items:QueryList<Item>;` But the QueryList object has a generic typed parameter (which since I am asking for any component, I am not sure how that would work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ng-template`, there's also an equivalent of implementing `ngFor`.
It is through:

```
<ng-template ngFor                            // Indication of your ngFor loop
             [ngForOf]="components"           // Your list
             let-component                    // Your component from components
             let-i="index">                   // Your index
    ...
</ng-template>
```

Attached **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-template-ngfor?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your reference.

---

If you want to render dynamic components inside an array, it's best to handle them in `ngSwitchCase`

**AppComponent**

```
// components = ['brother', 'sister', 'baby'];

<my-parent *ngFor="let component of components"     
           [component]="component">
</my-parent>
```

**ParentComponent (handles the ngSwitch)**

```
<div>

  <div [ngSwitch]="component">                             // Whatever value passed inside the @Input() component, it will render the component based on the conditions or cases below

    <my-brother *ngSwitchCase="'brother'"></my-brother>    // BrotherComponent

    <my-sister *ngSwitchCase="'sister'"></my-sister>       // SisterComponent

    <my-baby *ngSwitchCase="'baby'"></my-baby>             // BabyComponent
    
  </div>

</div>
```

- So if the `components` array value is `['brother', 'sister', 'baby'];` it will render the 3 components above
- if it's just `['brother', 'baby'];` it will only render the `BrotherComponent` and `BabyComponent`

Attached another **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-template-ngswitchcase?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your reference

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you for the help!